# Style Sheets: Setting up a style sheet to change only styles, no other fields

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, qgis-2.10, qml

I'm trying to create style sheets for my projects. I only wish to change the Style, without affecting labelling or the Fields. And I can't, for the life of me, get it to work. I'm using .qml files and editing using notepad/textpad.

Comment: Why are you not editing the style using QGIS?  QGIS will export the style in the right format rather than Notepad,   Surely a visual QGIS GUI is a safer and easier environment than an unrelated text editor.  If there is a pressing need to use Notepad, please edit your question to explain it.

Comment: its possible to change some component of .qml with text editor (e.g color). can you be more specific the changing that you did ?

Comment: Within QGIS there are only so many options, I made the original .gml in QGIS. Editing afterwards, however, is difficult within QGIS. As I'm sure you know @MappaGnosis, saving a style sheet with QGIS saves all of the settings, including field names and the number of geometries.I'm essentially setting up a style sheet for a categorised display. I only wish to change options under the "Style" tab, rather than all.

Comment: I should emphasise, I don't want to edit a single project. I want to save the style sheet to add to multiple different projects to line them up to a industry standard.

Comment: I appreciate that you want to use the style in multiple projects but the only place you can use a QML is in QGIS. So if you are trying to define something in Notepad that is not understood by QGIS, it will inevitably fail.  Your question lacks detail on exactly what you are trying to achieve, so it's very difficult to offer specific advice. Perhaps rules-based styles would be better than Categorised or switching to SLD rather than QML, but we can't tell. Suffice to say, my gut feeling is that hacking the QML by hand is not the best way to achieve your results (as you've discovered).

Comment: Either way, when saving a style sheet it will save the field categories and apply them to a new project. That was the issue here, rather than my method of editing.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your edit, here's a suggestion.  Stop using QML and switch to SLD.  When you save the SLD from QGIS, it doesn't contain the labeling (at least not in v 2.7.2). SLD is an open standard by OGC based on XML schema. See the SLD spec [here](http://file:///C:/Users/JB/Downloads/02-070_Styled_Layer_Descriptor_Implementation_Specification.pdf).  Just create your style as before but export to SLD and you can edit in Notepad (using the SLD reference).  I advocate Notepad ++ which will give you colour coding (you need to manually tell Notepad ++ that the language is XML to get the nice format).

SLD ***can*** contain information about labeling but doesn't have to and QGIS is happy about that.  What's more SLD is usable in many different technologies and not just QGIS so your style would work (probably - see below) in GeoServer for instance.

The only warning I would give you is that, a bit like SQL, SLD has a few 'dialects' (despite the standard) mostly in the form of 'vendor-specific' options, so occasionally an SLD created in QGIS might not work in another GIS technology and vice versa.  But anything created in QGIS is safe in QGIS.

A final note.  You say you are using the style in different projects.  Any style whether QML, SLD or CSS presupposes that the field(s) you are categorising/styling on exist and are identically named in all the data sets to which you apply the style.  If not, obviously, you will have to either normalise your data attribute names or edit your styles for each dataset.

Comment: This still doesn't work when styling by category, it adds the category field values as labels for the saved .sld. To be honest, rule based styling may work, however I have no clue (yet) how to set up the rule as I need it...